# How to create jar which can't be decompile

Tags: java, jar, decompiling

Hi I have to create a jar which will be send to our client.But issue is client can decompile the jar and do changes according to his requirement. I want to create the jar such that client can't read the code and can't do any changes in it. Can any body tell me the best solution for this

Comment: **No chance!** You can obfuscate the code to make it more difficult. But the code will always be readable because the target *computer* has to read and interpret the code. Therefore the code is there and must be interpretable, even for a human.

Comment: see http://www.excelsior-usa.com/articles/java-obfuscators.html

Comment: It's very unlikely that the client would decompile your jar and do changes. If so, you can always threaten legal action.

Comment: Security by obscurity has never worked; why do you want to do that anyway?

Comment: Does these obfuscator allow to obfuscate selective classes in the jar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't really deny the client any access to the code, otherwise he won't be able to execute it. Java bytecode can be decompiled.

The best you can do is to obfuscate it (rename all variables, classes and methods to `a`, `b`, `c` etc.) so it will be harder to understand what your code does and reuse it in other projects. I had rather positive experience with [ProGuard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/) which does this automatically on compiled classes.

Comment: Does these obfuscator allow to obfuscate selective classes in the jar

Comment: Yes. You can configure it to keep certain class names or entire classes unobfuscated. Can you explain why do you want to obfuscate only particular classes vs the whole project?

Comment: actually my senior asked for this facility.